# Tesseract Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV Error

Tags: android, bitmap, ocr, tesseract

I'm have an error in may android application it's : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
After following the error I found that it happend at this point of may code :
the Code

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

            //the error happened here
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();
```

things I do before calling this method:
1 - taking a picture
2 - crop it with size `x = 500` and `y = 100`
3 - save it as `Uri` in `_path` variable
4 - decode it to `bitmap` with `options.inSampleSize = 2;`

so if anyone know anything about this error please leave a comment. thank you.

Comment: You should include the stack trace from LogCat too.

Comment: Also try it on an emulator with a lot of RAM defined. You could be just running out of RAM on your device.

Comment: @rmtheis I had also faced the same problem. But i am using the real device, i also tried to use another version of api. But nothing helped. what can i do?

Comment: @ImMathan create a new StackOverflow question with more details about your situation. Don't forget to include whether you did the ndk-build step, whether you installed the traineddata on the device, and how you are calling init().

Comment: @rmtheis I asked the question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152620/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-error-in-tesseract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it .... the problem was with the `eng.trainedat`a file that handle the recognition operation, I downloaded another one from the Tesseract project site and the problem gone.

thanks for helping

Comment: Which version did you download? I have Tess 3.02