# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Error in Tesseract

Tags: android, bitmap, ocr, tesseract

I have developing an android ocr app with [Tesseract](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) Library.

And I build the project with ndk-build. And I created my project and placed the **eng.trainneddata(version 3.02)** in the *assets* folder of my application and when I started my application I copied the file to the **tessdata** folder into my folder **tivs**.

And i emulated into my one of the device with 1GB of RAM and 900MB free space of my phone it works perfectly.  I tested that in my another device (Moto e) it tells the error Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when i calls the getUTF8 Text().

**EDIT:**

```
public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TIVS/";
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
    baseApi.setRectangle(20,400,600,100); // I forgot to add this line
    String recognized_text = baseApi.getUTF8Text(); //Error occuring on this line
```

It continuously falls the same error all other devices.

Comment: What is `DATA_PATH`? Did you ensure that the trained data file is being copied onto the device?

Comment: I updated it @rmtheis. And i double checked the the tessdata is copied into my device.

Comment: So you're saying that you do *everything* *EXACTLY* *the* *same* on the emulator and on the device, but it only fails on the device? Is it the same bitmap? Have you tried running the tess-two-test unit tests on the emulator and the device?

Comment: No no i tried only with the device.. It succeeds on one of my device and not on another.. I haven't tried your unit tests yet..

Comment: @rmtheis I have checked the whole day but cant find out what is the problem. Help me out.

Comment: Are you using the same image on both devices? How big is it? Can you attach it? What is `lang`? Have you tried re-downloading your traineddata files?

Comment: Sorry @rmtheis. I actually forgot to add the line that i mentioned. And i debugged that it was actually the error. I was plotting rectangle above the actually bitmap dimensions. So that was the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working.